# Is it possible to convert string column to datetime in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table CUSTOMERS (ID,NAME,REGISTRATION_DT). It has following values -

1,Alex,093013 
2,Peter,012512
3,Mary,041911
.
.
.

I want to be able to select REGISTRATION_DT column and have the values retun as DATETIME. Is there any query to convert the existing varchar datatype in REGISTRATION_DT column to datetime and have all values in datetime format? The existing varchar values are in ddmmyy format.

I am using sql-server 2008

Comment: Assuming this is an ETL issue, you might want to write a function that takes the date string and an epoch year (for instance, if your epoch year is 1970, any two digit year after 69 would be in the 20th century, but any two digit year before 70 would be in the 21st century) and returns a date. If it isn't ETL, you should change the data type of the column to DATETIME or SMALLDATETIME and fix the application code that writes to that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below example requires the year to always be in 2000. you will also need to change the string YourTable to the table you want to query from.

```
SELECT
      Id
     ,Name
     --Convert To Date Time
     ,CONVERT(datetime,
                -- Add 20 to the final 2 numbers to represent the year i.e 2013
                ('20' + SUBSTRING(REGISTRATION_DT,5,2)
                    + '-' + 
                -- the first 2 numbers to represent the Month i.e 09
                SUBSTRING(REGISTRATION_DT,1,2)
                    + '-' + 
                -- the middle 2 numbers to represent the day i.e 30
                SUBSTRING(REGISTRATION_DT,3,2))) 
     as REGISTRATION_DT
from YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks @Luke Franklin for answering the question and explaining the logic in comments. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to convert the varchar to date. Try something like

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, LEFT(REGISTRATION_DT, 2) + '/'  
                       + LEFT(RIGHT(REGISTRATION_DT, 4), 2)
                       + '/20' + RIGHT(REGISTRATION_DT, 2))
```

An example [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32150) here.

More importantly though, you must consider changing the way you save the `REGISTRATION_DT` field in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
select ID, NAME ,CAST((substring(REGISTRATION_DT,5,6)+
substring(REGISTRATION_DT,1,4)) as datetime) 
as Registration_Date  from CUSTOMERS
```

As example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32154/0